# I trying to enter value to text area using vbscript but i am not able fill. text are tag dont have id it have only name

Tags: vbscript, textarea

HTML code :

```
<textarea name="q", class="classname" placeholder="enter the search content"><\textarea>
```

and it is inside table and table is inside form I tried to use document.forms but I didn't get expected output.

I tried  with `document.getelementbyname("q").placeholder = "value"`